# unable to add spark to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, apache-spark, pythonpath

I am struggling to add spark to my python path:

```
(myenv)me@me /home/me$ set SPARK_HOME="/home/me/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4"
(myenv)me@me /home/me$ set PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$SPARK_HOME:$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$SPARK_HOME/bin

(myenv)me@me /home/me$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/home/me/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python2.7', '/home/me/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/me/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/me/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/me/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/me/.virtualenvs/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/me/.virtualenvs/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

(myenv)me@me /home/me$ python -c 'import pyspark'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyspark
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pyspark for use in standalone scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205264/how-do-i-install-pyspark-for-use-in-standalone-scripts)

Answer (score 7):

I've got the same problem, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256536/importing-pyspark-in-python-shell?lq=1)   helped.

Just add the following command in your .bashrc

```
export SPARK_HOME=/path/to/your/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808064/pyspark-append-executor-environment-variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path`. But are you sure you need to modify `PYTHONPATH` if you have `pyspark` installed properly?

EDIT:

I haven't used pyspark, but would this help? 
[importing pyspark in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256536/importing-pyspark-in-python-shell)

Comment: pyspark is installed. I can run it in shell mode but I can't debug the code using an IDE - I get the ImportError.

Comment: @cheeech That's because you didn't set correct python interpreter in your IDE. Apparently you're using env, then you should set your virtualenv as your project interpreter.

Comment: the env interpreter is set in the IDE. The issue is external to the IDE (I am running the python commands on the command line).

Comment: How did you install pyspark?

Comment: downloaded and extracted http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/spark/spark-1.2.1/spark-1.2.1.tgz

Comment: I tried it both with source code package and pre-built for hadoop