# Sparkit-Learn import error

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache-spark, pyspark

During execution of following simple code with Sparkit-Learn:

```
from splearn.svm import SparkLinearSVC
spark=SparkLinearSVC()
```

I get following error message:

```
ImportError: pyspark home needs to be added to PYTHONPATH.
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$SPARK_HOME/python:../
```

In accordance with those anserws:
[unable to add spark to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829757/unable-to-add-spark-to-pythonpath)
[importing pyspark in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256536/importing-pyspark-in-python-shell)
I have added every possible configuration of those PYTHONPATHs to my .bashrc,but error is still occuring.

Currently my .bashrc paths looks like that:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/home/123/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
export SPARK_HOME=/home/123/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

Any possible solution?