# Ubuntu install apache spark via apt-get

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache-spark

I need to install spark and run it in standalone mode on one machine and looking for a straight forward way to install it via apt-get

I found how to do this with pyspark via pip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205264/how-do-i-install-pyspark-for-use-in-standalone-scripts)

I can not find any way to install spark with one terminal command.

Does installing pyspark install all the spark software?

I found [instructions](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2016/12/07/install-apache-spark-2-on-ubuntu-16-dot-04-and-mac-os/) for how to install spark, and it's more complex

Is there a way to install spark with a similar one terminal command via apt-get?

EDIT

I found [this](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_spark_install.html) explaining how to install spark using apt-get and i get the following error

> E: Unable to locate package spark-core E: Unable to locate package
>   spark-master E: Unable to locate package spark-worker E: Unable to
>   locate package spark-history-server E: Unable to locate package
>   spark-python

Thanks

Comment: Check this link http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/10/31/install-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/

Comment: thanks @VíctorLópez , but this is not via apt-get and does not explain if pyspark is a substitute for spark?

Comment: Could you please post the output of `sudo apt-get install spark` command?  
I just executed it on my Linux Mint (based od Ubuntu) and it worked without a problem.

Comment: @kchomski see edit

Comment: @kchomski `sudo apt-get install spark` will install the "SPARK programming language toolset" based on the Ada programming language (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/devel/spark). This is not(!) "Apache Spark".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before installing pyspark you must install Java8. This is described at

- http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html
- http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

For a fully automatic installation of Java8 on Ubuntu do

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get -y install software-properties-common
$ add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
$ echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
$ echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer
```

(see https://newfivefour.com/docker-java8-auto-install.html)

Afterwards you can simply run `pip install pyspark`.

Comment: could you explain how to download a complete spark via terminal? this one i mean https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: You don't need to download spark if you are using `pip install pyspark`.

Comment: you can not use the full functionality of spark with pyspark, for instance, you can't start a master or a slave on your machine using pyspark, you can only use an existing spark cluster that already been set on another machine

Comment: I was able to use pyspark using `import pyspark;
sc=pyspark.SparkContext()`. This will by default use the master-url  `local[*]` . (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) . I didn't need to setup a spark cluster to be able to do that.

Comment: In case you still want to download full spark via terminal, do `curl -LJO "https://www.apache.org/dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi?action=download&filename=spark/spark-2.2.0/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz"`