Is there a way to run pyspark in docker container?
I'm trying to run pyspark in a docker container, but I'm getting this error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/find_spark_home.py", line 95, in <module>
print(_find_spark_home())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/find_spark_home.py", line 59, in _find_spark_home
module_home = os.path.dirname(find_spec("pyspark").origin)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'
/home/airflow/.local/bin/pyspark: line 24: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/home/airflow/.local/bin/pyspark: line 68: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
This is my dockerfile :
FROM apache/airflow:2.9.0

USER root
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
openjdk-17-jre-headless \
&& apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/\*

RUN pip install pyspark

USER airflow
RUN pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon

I've tried many things, but I'm still stuck on this error.
Thanks a lot for your help !

Since it's complaining about not finding a pyspark directory under the airflow user's home directory, I would try installing pyspark after switching to the airflow user. That is, switching line 11 and 13 around.

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276984/ubuntu-install-apache-spark-via-apt-get
