# Pyspark installation with python 2.6

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-2.6

I have a production cluster with no internet connection and I would like to run spark scripts. Also, I only have installed python 2.6 and I cannot install 2.7
Considering these limitations where can I find the python package for pyspark 1.6.0?

Best regards, João

Comment: You can download spark 1.6.0 from [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) and manually install it. (navigate to python/pyspark and install it)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. How can I install pyspark python library with the pyspark binary?

Comment: oh i see. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205264/how-do-i-install-pyspark-for-use-in-standalone-scripts thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, good luck! :)

Comment: pyspark is part of the Spark distribution, you don't need to download it separately

Comment: @mkaran, you should answer the question so the OP may accept it and make it clear how the issue was solved. The way it is, it seems this question has no answer, which is untrue. It will also better document the question, keep SO cleaner, and grant you some SO points. Wouldn't that be nice for everyone?

Answer (score 0):

Adding here from the comments as Igor Donin suggested:

You can download spark 1.6.0 or other older versions from [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) and manually install it: navigate to python/pyspark and install it.

As you've commented, the way to install it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25209717/3433323)